# Convert Declarative Pipeline environment variable format to Scripted Pipeline environment variable format

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I had a scripted pipeline where I need to use environment variable which is mentioned as Declarative Pipeline format. Can you please let me know how to convert the environment variable from declarative to scripted pipeline. The variable in Declarative pipeline is a Global variable.

Declarative Pipeline environment variable.

environment {

```
AUTH_TOKEN = credentials('SCAN_AUTH_TOKEN')
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!groovy
def projectId
node('test-node')
{
stage('Fortify') 
    {   
             projectId = "Storeproject"
             withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'FORTIFY_TOKEN',   variable: 'SECRET')])
              { 
               credentialToReUse = "${SECRET}" ;
                sh """
                    echo $projectId;
                    echo $credentialToReUse
                    
                    """
                
               } 
          
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In scripted Piepline to assign a secret to an environment variable, you have to do like :

```
node {
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'SCAN_AUTH_TOKEN', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
    sh '''
      set +x
      curl -H "Token: $TOKEN" https://some.api/
    '''
  }
}
```

There are many types of credentials you can bind to a env variable. more details can be found [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/)

In another way (not a credential) you can make use of Env variable like this:

```
node('windows') {
    withEnv(['DISABLE_AUTH=true',
             'DB_ENGINE=sqlite']) {
        stage('Build') {
            echo "Database engine is ${DB_ENGINE}"
            echo "DISABLE_AUTH is ${DISABLE_AUTH}"
            sh 'printenv'
        }
    }
}
```